# Chrome App : Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy, chrome-app-developer-tool

I did some research on the same thread and tried the answers that I got. But still, the same error throws every time.

In my case, it's a chrome app and on one page I'm using an iframe and I'm pointing src into some XHTML content. That actually contain some inline style and scripts, which I cant remove or change.

Below is my manifest file.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "*****",
    "short_name": "****",
    "version": "*****",
    "permissions": [""],
    "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self'; object-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'",
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["chrome.js"]
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "1.png",
        "48": "2.png",
        "128": "3.png"
        },
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": [
            "****.html"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the the [Content Security Policy guidelines](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy):

> Inline Script
>
> Up until Chrome 45, there was no mechanism for relaxing the
>   restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular,
>   setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no
>   effect.
>
> As of Chrome 46, inline scripts can be whitelisted by specifying the
>   base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy. This hash must
>   be prefixed by the used hash algorithm (sha256, sha384 or sha512). See
>   Hash usage for  elements for an example.

Comment: I released this app when chrome was 51, that time the same manifest configuration works fine. So are u saying that hashing is the only solution?

Comment: more over that that script coming from the xhtml is dynamic.

Comment: perhaps show the html you are trying to load and explain how you are loading it?

Comment: main html
---------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe src="abc.com/xyz.xhtml" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

xyz.xhtml
---------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  .asdsd{
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
  }
 </style>
 <script>
 if(a) {
  // do this
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div>
   ---
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It isn't being loaded over https?